# Should I create an object or work with an array?

Tags: php, oop, iteration

I am fairly new to `OOP PHP` and as I am building my first project, I am coming across some difficult dilemmas.

I'm trying to build a forum. Yes, I know there are many free ones out there, I just want to have one that I can build according to my own needs :). Plus, it's fun to code.

I have build a base model and controller and template, for the forum, thread and post.
The base model has standard database functions, like find all, find by id etc. The individual models extend the model class and have only specific functions to the class.
I have set it up like this:

```
class Post_Model extends Model {

    static protected $_table_name = 'post';
    static protected $_db_fields = array('id', 'thread_id', 'parent_id', 'username', 'user_id',
        'title', 'date_line', 'pagetext', 'show_signature', 'ip_address', 'icon_id', 'visible');

    /**
     * @var db fields
     */
    public $id;
    public $thread_id;
    public $parent_id;
    public $username;
    public $user_id;
    public $title;
    public $date_line;
    public $pagetext;
    public $show_signature;
    public $ip_address;
    public $icon_id;
    public $visible;
}
/*
 * joined fields with user object. needed to display posts in all details
 */

static public function get_posts($id, $limit, $offset){
    $result_set = static::find_by_sql("
        SELECT * 
        FROM post 
        LEFT JOIN user ON (post.user_id = user.id) where post.thread_id=".(int)$id." 
        ORDER BY date_line DESC 
        LIMIT {$offset} , {$limit}");

    return !empty($result_set) ? $result_set : false;  
}
```

And besides the decisions that were tough, that I already had to make about certain functions and variables being static or not. I have this dilemma:

The basic CRUD works from the base model. That is fine, I can create, update, delete and read from my database through calling static methods from the (base) model, which instantiates objects for these forum, thread and post models. So far so good.

Part of the `Model Class`:

```
    <?php
        /**
     * Find rows from database based on sql statement
     * @param string $sql
     * @retun array $result_set
     */
    static public function find_by_sql($sql = '') {
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($record = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $object_array[] = static::instantiate($record);
        }
        return $object_array;
    }

    private static function instantiate($record) {
        $object = new static;
        foreach ($record as $attribute => $value) {
            if ($object->has_attritube($attribute)) {
                $object->$attribute = $value;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
}
?>
```

I transfer these objects for displaying in my templates. When reading from one table, that works just fine.

```
    <?php
$postcount = $pagination->offset + 1;
if (!empty($posts)) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        ?>

        <div class="post">
            <div class="posttime"><?php echo strftime("%A %e %B %G  %H:%M", $post->date_line); ?></div>
            <div class="postnumber">#<?php echo $postcount; ?></div>
            <div class="postuser">
                <div class="username"><?php echo $post->username; ?></div>
                <div class="avatar">avatar</div>
            </div>
            <div class="postcontents">
                <div class="posttext"><?php echo $post->pagetext; ?></div>  
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        $postcount++;
    }
    ?>    
<div class="pagination"><?php echo $page_split; ?></div>
```

However, for the display of all posts in the threads, I need info from the user table, e.g. there number of their posts, rank, avatar etc.

Okay, so here's the thing:

```
SELECT * FROM post
LEFT JOIN user ON (post.user_id = user.id)
where thread_id={$id}
ORDER BY date_line DESC
LIMIT {$offset} , {limit}
```

I now have more fields then variables that I have setup in my Post model. So they are not transferred for displaying.

Should I use an array for displaying these extra fields instead of object? I would rather still use the object approach for displaying, as I am now set up for that.

Or should I maybe add these user fields as variables to my Post model? I am thinking that is not the most tidy way to do it, however it would work.

Or should I go through a `foreach` loop to get a separate instance of a (yet to create) user class? I am thinking it would drain much more memory then the Left Join that simply gets me the data that I need.

I would like some hints on how you would solve this.

Comment: Static variables are not part of object oriented paradigm. Model is a layer, not an abstraction for DB table. Which also make "post model" a meaningless thing.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am trying to learn this myself, so I am dependent on what I have learned in some online courses that I took. I am trying to combine what i learned in these things. I might not have gotten the best information, probably. How would you set it up then, roughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to solve this with your schema, because you are mixing properties from different entities in your `Post` entity [i.e. username].

The idea is that you just have to make your code aware of the **relationship** between entities, like:

```
class Post extends Entity
{

  protected $id;
  protected $body;
  protected $date;

  // this will be an instance of a Thread entity, let's say
  protected $thread;

  // this will be an instance of the User entity
  protected $user;

  ...

}
```

This way you will be able to do:

```
$somePost -> getUser() -> getAvatar();
```

But how do you inject the correct user and thread to each post? That's what [**Object Relational Mappers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) are for: in you case, all the SQL stuff would be handled by the ORM, and you'll be just dealing with you object graph, with no worries about building queries on your own; you just have to define such relationships.

A popular PHP ORM is [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/in-ten-quick-steps.html): [here is an example about how it handles relationships declarations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/yaml-mapping.html).

Of course this approach has downsides, but it's up to you investigating and finding out the best tradeoff between flexibility and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! Just when I think I am getting close.... I find out I have a lot to learn here ... I will investigate it for sure. It at least gets me into another thinking pattern, thanks.

Comment: So am I understanding the main "idea" here? Controller gets the info from the Model and passes it on to the View. And the model tells this Mapper i need this info from the database... go get it for me?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that might break out the dilemma; in PHP an object can also [act as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) (or [even a function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)!) but a normal plain array cannot have properties or any other OOP feature.

Comment: maybe i should not instantiate an object of the class Post_Model at all but hardcode the creation of this standard object with all the fields that i need.

Comment: I have to say.. it is SO hard to learn this on your own... I am trying to learn how to do it the best way and everybody has a different opinion. All i can do is google for opinions basically... but WHAT is the actual right way to build up this system... that's a brainbreaker for me.